# Netbeans - Set project to upload the related css file when making changes to an scss file

Tags: css, netbeans, upload, sass

In netbeans, I am looking to automatically upload the css file related to the scss file I am editing on save to a remote server. Does anybody know what settings I would need to change to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you deploy your application with a war file or ear on your remote server. So for anything to take effect on that application it must be build inside that file and then take effect on your application.

So, bottom line, what you are asking is practical y impossible.